# Detect IP subnet overlap from mySQL database

Tags: mysql

I have a database with a list of IP ranges in my corporate infrastructure. I want to identify any subnet ranges that are overlapping.

I was using the code below which converts the IPs into decimal numbers then searches for any ending IP that appears in all ranges more than once. I'd run the same code again for the `starting_ip` then combine the lists; however, I've identified a few ranges that are not showing up as a result. Is there a better way to do this?

```
SELECT 
    COUNT(*), supernet, starting_ip, ending_ip, inet_aton(starting_ip), inet_aton(ending_ip)
FROM
    IPLookup.ADsegments
WHERE
    INET_ATON(ending_ip) BETWEEN INET_ATON(starting_ip) AND INET_ATON(ending_ip)
GROUP BY starting_ip
HAVING COUNT(*) > 1 ;
```

Example of a overlap not detected:

| supernet | starting_ip | ending_ip |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 10.12.0.0/16 | 10.12.0.1 | 10.12.255.254 |
| 10.12.114.0/24 | 10.12.114.1 | 10.12.114.254 |
| 10.12.128.0/17 | 10.12.128.1 | 10.12.255.254 |
| 10.12.180.0/24 | 10.12.180.1 | 10.12.180.254 |
| 10.12.64.0/18 | 10.12.64.1 | 10.12.127.254 |

I have 2 class A networks to crawl through. I've already cut it down the list to subnet ranges where I'm expecting clients to show up, but that still ~4000 rows.

I'm not really concerned with the time it takes to execute because I have a private server to do this kind of reporting on.

The query is happening way too fast (completes in 0.02 seconds). I suspect I don't have the right query or am hitting some sort of limit.

IPv6 isn't being used yet in the company.

Answer (score 0):

> The query is happening way too fast (completes in 0.02 seconds).

Yeah, that sounds too fast.  I would expect having to hit 4000 * 4000 rows to perform the query.

If you have some application code in front of the query, write most of the code there.  Use only `SELECT ... FROM ADsegments ORDER BY INET_ATON(starting_ip)`.

You would be better off storing in `INT UNSIGNED` and not having to repeatedly call `INET_ATON`. - [user1876](https://dba.stackexchange.com/u/1876)